# Python Flet AttributeError: module 'flet_core.page' has no attribute 'controls'

Tags: python, flet

In summary, I am at the very beginning of the project.

What I'm trying to do is use a custom 'navigation rail' for navigation between pages.Now there is a problem. When I use the custom navigation rail alone, the program works, but when I want to integrate it into my project, I get an error.
error = AttributeError: module 'flet_core.page' has no attribute 'controls'

*
*

This is the code that works when I use the custom navigation rail alone.

```
import flet
from flet import *
from functools import partial
import time




class ModernNavBar(UserControl):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func = func
        super().__init__()


    def HighLight(self,e):
        print("e = "+str(e.data))
        if e.data == "true":
            print("girdi")
            e.control.bgcolor = "white10"
            e.control.update()

            e.control.content.controls[0].icon_color = "white"
            e.control.content.controls[1].color = "white"
            e.control.content.update()
        else:

            e.control.bgcolor=None
            e.control.update()

            e.control.content.controls[0].icon_color = "white54"
            e.control.content.controls[1].color = "white54"
            e.control.content.update()

    def UserData(self,initialise:str,name:str,description:str):

        return Container(
            content=Row(
                controls=[
                    Container(
                        width=42,
                        height=42,
                        bgcolor="bluegrey900",
                        alignment=alignment.center,
                        border_radius=8,
                        content=Text(
                            color="white",
                            value=initialise,
                            size=20,
                            weight="bold",
                        ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                        alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                        spacing=1,
                        controls=[
                            Text(
                                color="white",
                                value=name,
                                size=11,
                                weight="bold",
                                opacity=1,
                                animate_opacity=200,

                            ),
                            Text(
                                color="white54",
                                value=description,
                                size=9,
                                weight="bold",
                                opacity=1,
                                animate_opacity=200,

                            ),
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            )
        )
    def ContainedIcon(self,icon_name:str,text:str):
        return Container(
            width=180,
            height=45,
            border_radius=10,
            on_hover=lambda e: self.HighLight(e),
            on_click=None,
            content=Row(
                controls=[
                    IconButton(
                        icon=icon_name,
                        icon_size=18,
                        icon_color="white54",
                        style=ButtonStyle(
                            shape={
                                "":RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=7)
                            },
                            overlay_color={"":"transparent"}

                        )
                    ),
                    Text(
                        color="white54",
                        value=text,
                        size=9,
                        weight="bold",
                        opacity=1,
                        animate_opacity=200,

                    ),
                ]
            )
        )

    def build(self):
        return Container(
            width=200,
            height=580,
            padding=padding.only(top=10),
            alignment=alignment.center,

            content=Column(
                alignment=MainAxisAlignment.START,
                horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                controls=[
                    self.UserData("LI","Line Indent","Software"),
                    Container(
                        width=24,
                        height=24,
                        bgcolor="bluegrey800",
                        border_radius=8,
                        on_click=self.func

                    ),
                    Divider(height=5,color="transparent"),
                    self.ContainedIcon(icons.DASHBOARD,"Dashboard"),
                    self.ContainedIcon(icons.ANALYTICS, "Analytics"),

                    Divider(height=50,color="white24"),
                    self.ContainedIcon(icons.SETTINGS, "Settings"),

                ]
            )
        )


def main(page: Page):
    page.title = "Flet Modern Sidebar"

    page.horizontal_alignment = "center"
    page.vertical_alignment = "center"

    def AnimateSideBar(e):
        if page.controls[0].width != 62:
            for item in (
                    page.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[1]
                            .controls[:]
            ):
                item.opacity = 0
                item.update()

            for items in page.controls[0].content.controls[0].content.controls[3:]:
                if isinstance(items, Container):
                    items.content.controls[1].opacity = 0
                    items.content.update()
            time.sleep(0.2)

            page.controls[0].width = 62
            page.controls[0].update()
        else:

            page.controls[0].width = 200
            page.controls[0].update()

            time.sleep(0.2)

            for item in (
                    page.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[1]
                            .controls[:]
            ):
                item.opacity = 1
                item.update()

            for items in page.controls[0].content.controls[0].content.controls[3:]:
                if isinstance(items, Container):
                    items.content.controls[1].opacity = 1
                    items.content.update()


    page.add(Container(
        content=ModernNavBar(AnimateSideBar),
        padding=10,
        width=200,
        height=580,
        bgcolor="black",
        border_radius=20,
        alignment=alignment.center,
        animate = animation.Animation(500, "decelerate")

    ))

    page.update()
    print(str(page.controls[0]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flet.app(target=main)
```

When you run the page you see above, the program works perfectly.However, when I try to integrate it into a project as I will show below, I get an error.

I explain my code below:

- main page = the part required for the application to start
- route page = I control my app's navigation processes.
- home page = the first page my application opens. On this page, I put the navigation rail in a row. There will be navigation rail on the left side of the window, and other content on the right. When I press the button that triggers the animation inside the navigation rail, it gives an error

What I'm trying to do is fix the animation of the navigation rail and write a function for each item to go to another page

**main page**

```
    from flet import *
    from core.init.navigation.route import Router
    def main(page : Page):  
    
        def route_change(route):
            page.views.clear()
            page.views.append(
                Router(page)[page.route]
            )
    
        page.on_route_change=route_change
        page.go("/")
    app(target=main)
```

**route page**

```
  from flet import *
  from product.screens.main.main import Main

  def Router(page):

    return {
        "/":View(
            route="/",
            controls=[
                Main(page)
            ]
        ),
        "/b": View(
            route="/b",
            controls=[
                Container(height=800, width=350, bgcolor="blue")
            ]
        ),

    }
```

**home page**

```
  import time

  from flet import *

  from product.components.side_bar import ModernNavBar


  class Main(UserControl):
    def __init__(self,page):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = page

        page.controls.append(self)
        page.update()



        print("page ===== "+str(page.controls[0]))

    def _getControlName(self):
        return "Main"

    def AnimateSideBar(e, self=None):
        if page.controls[0].width != 62:
            for item in (
                    page.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[1]
                            .controls[:]
            ):
                item.opacity = 0
                item.update()

            for items in page.controls[0].content.controls[0].content.controls[3:]:
                if isinstance(items, Container):
                    items.content.controls[1].opacity = 0
                    items.content.update()
            time.sleep(0.2)

            page.controls[0].width = 62
            page.controls[0].update()
        else:

            page.controls[0].width = 200
            page.controls[0].update()

            time.sleep(0.2)

            for item in (
                    page.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[0]
                            .content.controls[1]
                            .controls[:]
            ):
                item.opacity = 1
                item.update()

            for items in page.controls[0].content.controls[0].content.controls[3:]:
                if isinstance(items, Container):
                    items.content.controls[1].opacity = 1
                    items.content.update()



    def build(self):
        return Container(
                    animate=animation.Animation(500, "decelerate"),
                    height=800,
                    width=200,
                    bgcolor="bluegrey",
                    content=Row(
                        controls=[
                            ModernNavBar(self.AnimateSideBar),
                            Text("Welcome to the homepage"),

                        ]
                    )

        )
```

**When you click the button you see in the photo, it gives the following error.**

[image]

> Exception in thread Thread-8: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\Yonet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py",
> line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "C:\Users\Yonet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py",
> line 910, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "D:\pycharmProjectFolder\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flet_core\event_handler.py",
> line 28, in __sync_handler
> h(r)   File "D:\pycharmProjectFolder\pythonProject\product\screens\main\main.py",
> line 24, in AnimateSideBar
> if page.controls[0].width != 62: AttributeError: module 'flet_core.page' has no attribute 'controls'

Answer (score -2):

seems like you were trying to use the wrong `page` object, therefore,  it didn't have your expected `controls` attribute.

In your `main.py` snippet, you have 2 possible `page` use cases, one would be from the import of flet (`from flet import *` == `from flet import page`), and the other one would be one of the `Main` class properties also called `page` (`self.page`).

So it looks like you wanted to access the controls of your page which is stored in `self.page` other then in the widget you import from the `flet` module.

Fix the `AnimateSideBar` function (I just replaced all `page` usages to `self.page` which has controls attribute in it like you used in the `__init__` function in `Main`):

```
def AnimateSideBar(self, e):
    if self.page.controls[0].width != 62:
        for item in (
                self.page.controls[0]
                        .content.controls[0]
                        .content.controls[0]
                        .content.controls[1]
                        .controls[:]
        ):
            item.opacity = 0
            item.update()

        for items in self.page.controls[0].content.controls[0].content.controls[3:]:
            if isinstance(items, Container):
                items.content.controls[1].opacity = 0
                items.content.update()
        time.sleep(0.2)

        self.page.controls[0].width = 62
        self.page.controls[0].update()
    else:

        self.page.controls[0].width = 200
        self.page.controls[0].update()

        time.sleep(0.2)

        for item in (
                self.page.controls[0]
                        .content.controls[0]
                        .content.controls[0]
                        .content.controls[1]
                        .controls[:]
        ):
            item.opacity = 1
            item.update()

        for items in self.page.controls[0].content.controls[0].content.controls[3:]:
            if isinstance(items, Container):
                items.content.controls[1].opacity = 1
                items.content.update()
```